# Monospaced detailedText in QMessageBox

Tags: qt, subclassing, qmessagebox

I've been using a `QMessageBox` to display the outcome of a statistical test. It's nice, because I can put a summary result in the informative text, then the full result in the detailed text. The trouble is, the full result is a table, so I'd like it to be monospaced so that it looks right, and `QMessageBox` doesn't use a monospace font in the detailed text area.

So I'm looking at either subclassing `QMessageBox`, or subclassing `QDialog` to make something that looks like a `QMessageBox` but uses a monospace font in the detailed text area. I'm a bit rusty at the moment, and having a hard time figuring out which is the better option. Could I subclass `QMessageBox`, just add my own `QTextEdit` and my own "show detailed text" button, and leave the `QMessageBox` detailed text area and button hidden? Or is there some easier way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use html text in the fields of a QMessageBox, that would be the easiest way. As a hint, try putting

```
 <pre>Test</pre>
```

in your QString.

Any other customization of the message box will probably imply a subclass, though.

Comment: HTML seems to work for the informative text, but not the detailed text. It seems to use ASCII (I can use special characters, like nonbreaking spaces, but have to use escaped ASCII codes for them as opposed to HTML codes). Tags like <pre> appear literally in the detailed text area.

Answer (score 4):

I did not find better than this:

```
setStyleSheet("QTextEdit { font-family: monospace; }");
```

It's a bit hacky because (1) it uses stylesheets, which may conflicts with your way of styling your widget and (2) it relies on the fact that the detailed text is in a `QTextEdit` and is the only such element, which is not officially ensured by the API. But it works. :D

Comment: Thanks.  This worked for me in C++ Qt version 4.7.4 for Windows and version 4.8.5 for Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example, based on the answer of [Lithy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38371503/4459346):

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

table_text = '\
Name    Flower\n\
------  -------\n\
Violet  Yes\n\
Robert  No\n\
Daisy   Yes\n\
Anna    No\n\
'

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        warning_text = 'warning_text'
        info_text = 'info_text'
        pt = 'colour  name'
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msg.setText(warning_text)
        msg.setInformativeText(info_text)
        msg.setDetailedText("{}".format(table_text))
        msg.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        # print all children and their children to find out which widget
        # is the one that contains the detailed text
        for child in msg.children():
            print('child:{}'.format(child))
            print(' {}'.format(child.children()))
        pname = 'QMessageBox'
        cname = 'QTextEdit'
        msg.setStyleSheet(
            """{} {} {{ background-color: red; color: black; font-family: Courier; }}""".format(pname, cname))
        msg.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Widget()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use html text in the detailedText of a QMessageBox using this hack:

```
QString html_formatted_text;
QMessageBox mb;
mb.setDetailedText(html_formatted_text);
// Find detailed text widget
auto te = mb.findChild<QTextEdit*>();
if (te) {
    te->setHtml(mb.detailedText());
}
mb.exec();
```